# jquery lightbox plugin: Bug on IE7 and IE8!

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, lightbox

I wonder if anyone has used this [lightbox plugin](http://designresourcebox.com/snippet/colorbox-lightbox-plugin/) and encountered a bug on IE < 9 ?

It keeps crashing my IE8, and IE7, but it is ok on IE9.

Any idea how to fix it?

or any other alternatives? I would like to use this lightbox plugin because it allows me to embed videos from youtube and vimeo. Other lightbox plugins which allow me to run videos will be perfect!

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Found the bug - **jquery-1.6.min.js** !!!

It works fine now with - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

I always encounter buggy things with jquery-1.6.min.js! **Hating** it!

Comment: need more information or some code to look at

Comment: found the problem - check my edit above. thanks.

Comment: I had a wise person once tell me it is better to use an older version of jQuery (like 1.5 or even 1.4) because the newer versions can be buggy. Let them work out the bugs then upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding lightboxing I always use prettyPhoto, because:

1. it’s very much flexible and it has an API which enables you to make your images totally and fully customizable without binding any data to your inline images.
2. Also if you are developing using a server side language then using this API makes your code more readable and maintainable.
3. it also supports, videos, iframes, etc...

Here is the pretty photo website:
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

and here is the API documentation (Bottom of the page):
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, [**Colorbox**](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is a great lightbox.

> [View the demo](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) to see how easily Colorbox 
>   works with YouTube.

It's lightweight at only ~10 KB and supports photos, grouping, slideshows, ajax, inline, and iframed content.

It works in Firefox 3+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Internet Explorer 6+, Opera 11.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to the end of your iframe source:

```
&amp;wmode=opaque
```

i.e.

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5_sfnQDr1-o&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Basically, earlier versions of Internet Explorer will treat an embedded YouTube video as the top-most element.

Source: http://howchoo.com/g/make-your-lightbox-display-over-an-embedded-youtube-video-in-ie8