# Start a Lightbox on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, lightbox

Not sure exactly how to do this since I am not that great at Javascript.

Here is what I would like to do:  A person goes to a page as soon as the page opens a lightbox opens automatically BEFORE the page loads any other content. The person will then read the information in the lightbox and have an a few options on how they want to proceed. While they read this information the rest of the page will load in the background.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Note: I am using Fancybox for my lightbox.

Comment: The only way to be sure you have all of Jquery and the required libraries loaded to do something like this is to draw your lightbox as soon as the 'ready' event is fired. Images will load behind the lightbox, but the page will be fully loaded. Unless you re-architect your site, to load partials via ajax requests, it will be very difficult to have the lightbox be present while HTML document content (not images, etc) actually loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend prettyPhoto, I has a cool API that allows you to open the lightbox from javascript.

Following the API documentation [here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/) you can do something like this to launch lightbox on load using JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $().prettyPhoto()
    api_images = ['images/fullscreen/image1.jpg','images/fullscreen/image2.jpg','images/fullscreen/image3.jpg'];
    api_titles = ['Title 1','Title 2','Title 3'];
    api_descriptions = ['Description 1','Description 2','Description 3'];
    $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,api_titles,api_descriptions);
  });
</script>
```

see my notes in this question:

[jquery lightbox plugin: Bug on IE7 and IE8!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445601/jquery-lightbox-plugin-bug-on-ie7-and-ie8/6445711#6445711)

Comment: Thanks, I looked at it but as I mentioned in the above post I am not that great at JS. Can you give me an example of launching the lightbox as soon as the page launches?

Comment: I tried your example and it did not work. It also broke the page itself (there are boxes that should show below the main image) Here is the page I am referring to: http://www.ubhape2.com/home2.html

Comment: you need to add $j().prettyPhoto(); before in the first line. see website documentation for all details about the API. - I tried it on your page and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Lynda's approach and also works fine here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

<!-- show Lightbox Image Details instantly on page load -->
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#YourImageId').trigger('click');
}); 

//]]>   
</script>

...

<img id="YourImageId" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to continue using fancybox at any time then here is how I managed to get fancybox to open on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $.fancybox({
                autoScale:          true,
                autoDimensions:     true,
                transitionIn:       'fade',
                transitionOut:      'fade',
                scrolling:          'no',
                centerOnScroll:     true,
                overlayShow:        true,
                content:            $('#somediv').html(),   
                padding:            20  
            });
        })(jQuery); 
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

That's how I managed it. Useful to know even if you don't use fancybox!

Answer (score 1):

I found this after I asked this question but I will post it here for others =>

the script below is for v1.3.0

```
1) inline
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#autostart").fancybox({
'width': 640,  //or whatever
'height': 400
});
}); // document ready

</script>

<body onload="$('#autostart').trigger('click');">

<a href="#mycontent" id="autostart">something here maybe</a>

<div style="display: none">
<p id="mycontent">I want to display this</p>
</div>

1) external html page:

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#autostart").fancybox({
'width': 640,  //or whatever
'height': 400.
'type': 'iframe' // see this?
 });
 }); // document ready

 </script>

<body onload="$('#autostart').trigger('click');">

<a href="http://domain.com/page-to-display.html"
id="autostart">something here maybe ... or not</a>
```